# How to insert an ID from an URL into database with checkboxes using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm trying to get the ID from an URL like this: (the 37 is the ID)

```
http://localhost/myQSP/public/assign-qsps.php?employeeName=37
```

And insert it into a database along with a checkbox selection.

Database

```
id | employees_fk | qsps_fk | checked
1       37            101        1
2       37            102        1
```

The qsps_fk is a relational table.  Using this Process code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $assign_qsps_id = $_POST["hidden-qsp-checkBoxes"];
    $hidden_qsp = $_POST["department-qsp-checkBoxes"];

    if(isset($_POST['hidden-qsp-checkBoxes'])) {

        foreach ($assign_qsps_id as $qsp_id){ 

        $visible_assign_qsp = in_array($qsp_id, $hidden_qsp) ? 1 : 0;

        $query = "INSERT INTO junction_employees_qsps (qsps_fk, checked) VALUES ($qsp_id, $visible_assign_qsp);
        $result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It will create a table like this

```
id | employees_fk | qsps_fk | checked
1        0            101        1
2        0            102        1
```

My form is

```
<form action="assign-qsps-process.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ASSIGN QSP'S" />
<ul>
    <?php $employee_qsps = find_departments_for_assign_qsps($current_employee['id']);

while($qsp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($employee_qsps)) { ?>
        <li>

        <input type='checkbox' name='hidden-qsp-checkBoxes[]' value='<?php htmlentities($qsp["qsp_id"]); ?>' style='display:none' checked='checked' />"; 

        <input type='checkbox' name='department-qsp-checkBoxes[]' value='<?php htmlentities($qsp["qsp_id"]); ?>' />

        <?php echo htmlentities($qsp['qsp_name']); ?>                       
       </li>
    }
    </ul>

</form>
```

So how do I get the ID from the URL inserted with the checkbox selection along with makeing the employees_fk a relational table?

I've tried this and it doesn't work.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $id_employee = $current_employee["id"];
    $assign_qsps_id = $_POST["hidden-qsp-checkBoxes"];
    $hidden_qsp = $_POST["department-qsp-checkBoxes"];

    if(isset($_POST['hidden-qsp-checkBoxes'])) {

        foreach ($assign_qsps_id as $qsp_id){ 

        $visible_assign_qsp = in_array($qsp_id, $hidden_qsp) ? 1 : 0;

        $query = "INSERT INTO junction_employees_qsps (employees_fk, qsps_fk, checked) VALUES ($id_employee, $qsp_id, $visible_assign_qsp);
        $result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you! I really appreciate the Help!

Comment: `$_GET['employeeName']` or `$_REQUEST['employeeName']` are your friends

Comment: So When I do this   $id_employee = $_REQUEST["employeeName"];  and run the same insert process nothing happens.  I've read that you can't do a _GET and _POST at the same time.  Is that why this is not working?

Comment: OK Got IT!  Not only did I need to use the $_GET but I needed to use a hidden field like this  <input type='hidden' name='employee_id' value=' <?php htmlentities($current_employee['id']) ?>' />